# Insert line using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm writing a bash script that installs a few elements on a server, and running into an issue.

I'm installing nginx - and by default it does not include sites-enabled and sites-available.

Using my script, I would create both, and include them in nginx.conf

I obviously make the directories using

```
mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-available
mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Now, I've tried the following, but failed:

```
sed '/include /etc/nginx/mime.types;/a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And:

```
sed 'include /etc/nginx/mime.types;/a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And:

```
OLDLINE = 'include /etc/nginx/mime.types;'
NEWLINE = 'include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;'

sed 'OLDLINE/a NEWLINE' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And:

```
OLDLINE = 'include /etc/nginx/mime.types;'
NEWLINE = 'include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;'

sed '/OLDLINE/a NEWLINE' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And:

```
OLDLINE = "include /etc/nginx/mime.types;"
NEWLINE = "include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;"

sed 'OLDLINE/a NEWLINE' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This is not a good way of managing system configurations. Consider something like `puppet`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `sed` command is that the patterns contain `/` characters which conflict with the command delimiters.
If you still want to tackle this problem with `sed`, the simple solution would be to escape every slash in the patterns:

```
sed '/include \/etc\/nginx\/mime.types;/a include \/etc\/nginx\/sites-enabled\/*;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But if you are alergic to the toothsaw effect, try forcing a different command separator like this:

```
sed '\@include /etc/nginx/mime.types;@a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;'  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Here we use `@` as the separator so the `/` characters don't need to be escaped anymore.

Note, that you can get `sed` to do in-place substitution with `-i` but that, I believe, is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 0):

In order to include the new lines

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
```

after the line:

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

You can use a `sed` expression that will **edit nginx.conf inline** (and create a backup of the original) by searching for the existing line `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` and then substituting a newline and the additions you want with the following:

```
sed -i.bak '/include \/etc\/nginx\/mime.types;/s|$|\ninclude /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;\ninclude /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;|' nginx.conf
```

Which will create `nginx.conf.bak` holding the original conf file and modify `nginx.conf` to contain:

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
```